# New GIT Branch, Used Name, Fresh History

Tags: git, branch

I had a branch named "Development" a year ago.  It is long-gone.

I just recently made a new branch named "Development" off of my master... but all the history from the old Development branch is there.  How do I have my "New" Development branch have a fresh start of history?  Do I need to name it Dev2?

Comment: It sounds like your old `Development` branch was never deleted.  Try deleting it first (`git branch -D Development`) and then creating a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's start on `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Then, delete your local `Development` branch:

```
git branch -D Development
```

Finally, let's create a new `Development` branch that is based off of `master`:

```
git checkout -b Development
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what do you want to achieve:

### Creating fork of current branch

Then this is not possible. The new branch will always copy the history of the branch from which you're creating it:

```
 git branch Development
```

`Development` branch will contain all the history as current branch.

### Create fresh empty branch

You can create completely empty branch with the following command:

```
git checkout --orphan Development
```

`Development` branch will have zero history and you can start from scratch. This usually doesn't make too much sense as there is no real way how to merge the two branches together later.

This approach is rather useful when you want to clean the history of repository in order to save space and things like that.